# Can't find module '@firebase/storage-types'

Tags: typescript, firebase

I have a very simple TypeScript file:

```
import { Reference } from "@firebase/storage-types";

export interface IReference extends Reference {
  getMetadata<T = any>(): Promise<T>;
  getDownloadURL(): Promise<string>;
}

export {
  FullMetadata as IFullMetadata,
  SettableMetadata as ISettableMetadata,
  UploadMetadata as IUploadMetadata,
  UploadTask as IUploadTask,
  UploadTaskSnapshot as IUploadTaskSnapshot,
  FirebaseStorage
} from "@firebase/storage-types";
```

And this transpiles to the following Javascript:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var storage_types_1 = require("@firebase/storage-types");
exports.FirebaseStorage = storage_types_1.FirebaseStorage;
```

Interestingly when I run it with `node lib/storage.js` it fails with:

> Error: Cannot find module '@firebase/storage-types'

The package **does** include this module as a dependency. Here is the full block:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.1.1",
    "@firebase/auth-types": "^0.1.1",
    "@firebase/database-types": "^0.1.1",
    "@firebase/firestore-types": "^0.2.1",
    "@firebase/messaging-types": "^0.1.1",
    "@firebase/storage-types": "^0.1.1",
    "@firebase/util": "^0.1.7"
  },
```

But it appears in cases where I'm proxying exports through to a container and *not* changing the name -- as I'm doing with `FirebaseStorage` -- then this results in a `require` statement that can not resolve.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: I believe the distinguishing trait that transpiles to the require is the exporting of a **Class** versus just **Interfaces**. I guess that makes some sense.

Comment: My further suspicion is that because these Google packages don't have a "main" section in their `package.json` it causes an issue in importing concrete code like Classes versus just typing like Interfaces. For what it's worth, all I'm interested in is typing information.

Comment: Are you saying it wants a require statement instead of the usual TS import statement?

Comment: In the Typescript I'm only wanting to convey type not actual logic. Therefore, when transpiled I'd expect the useful content to be in the `index.d.ts` file not the `index.js` file. In Typescript I'm using the ES module syntax (aka, _import_) but in anything that ends up in the JS file it is transpiled to CommonJS (aka, _require_).